# ErrorDocument 403 custom page not displays

Tags: html, ip

I've blocked all IP's except my own from an old website, I've added a custom HTML page to replace the default 403, but it's not displaying?

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from (ip)
allow from (ip)
ErrorDocument 403 http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/error.html
```

I can access the html page in my browser by visiting www.mywebsite.co.uk/error.html but from a blocked IP it still displays the standard 403 error message

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should restart your web service (nginx/apache/other). I was stuck with nginx "cache" for my new SSL certificate and restarting Nginx solved this.

Comment: This needs clarification - is it on Apache? Did you restart Apache after making the change? It could be that `ErrorDocument` doesn’t work with absolute URLs, I don’t remember - either way, try a local path `/error.html`

Comment: @Delphine Ah, yes restarting Apache worked.. why do I not think of simple things first! Thanks for the input :)